# java compiling error: -Xlint causing problems

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

Basically, there are 2 frames: "StartUpFrame" and "ActivityScreen"
The StartUpFrame was made using purely **Netbeans GUI**, whereas ActivityScreen was made through **coding without any Netbeans GUI**.

On the StartUpFrame, when I press the button "List of Activities", it should switch the frame to ActivityScreen, which should be a very simple operation.

However, when I compiled ActivityScreen on its own, it gave me some warnings similar to:

"*Note: F:\Java\Lab 8\Lab8.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.*",
but the file still did compile.

And when I try to compile StartUpFrame, the error seems to be causing a problem with the button action, unable to call the class properly

I just can't figure out what the problem is.

**The StartUpFrame.java**

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StartUpFrame extends JFrame
{

    //Creates new form StartUpFrame
    public StartUpFrame() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        title = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnActivities = new javax.swing.JButton();
        ButtonExit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnStudents = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        title.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
        title.setText("ASA Magement Program");

        btnActivities.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        btnActivities.setText("List of Activities");
        btnActivities.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnActivitiesActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        ButtonExit.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        ButtonExit.setText("Exit");
        ButtonExit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ButtonExitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnStudents.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        btnStudents.setText("List of All Students");
        btnStudents.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnStudentsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(233, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnActivities)
                .addGap(232, 232, 232))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                        .addComponent(title))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(213, 213, 213)
                        .addComponent(btnStudents)))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(258, 258, 258)
                .addComponent(ButtonExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(title)
                .addGap(103, 103, 103)
                .addComponent(btnActivities)
                .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                .addComponent(btnStudents)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 110, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(ButtonExit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents


    private void ButtonExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_ButtonExitActionPerformed
        System.exit(0);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_ButtonExitActionPerformed

    private void btnActivitiesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnActivitiesActionPerformed

                ActivityScreen AS = new ActivityScreen();
                AS.setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);

    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnActivitiesActionPerformed

    private void btnStudentsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnStudentsActionPerformed


            StudentScreen SS = new StudentScreen();
            SS.setVisible(true);
            setVisible(false);

    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnStudentsActionPerformed

//the command line arguments
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
    // Create and display the form
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new StartUpFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    //note to self: NEED TO REMOVE "JAVAX.SWING."
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton ButtonExit;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnActivities;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnStudents;
    private javax.swing.JLabel title;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

**ActivityScreen.java**

```
       import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
        import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



    class MyFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
    {


     //Object[][] cell_value = {  {"Sunday","Activity1","Activity2","Activity3"},  {"Monday","Activity4","Activity5","Activity6"},  {"Tuesday","Activity7","Activity8",""}};
     Object[][] cell_value = new Object[0][5];


     //String ColName[] = { "Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"};
       String ColName[] = new String [5];

     MyFrame()
     {
        try{ 
                String s = "";
                int n = 0;
                int m = 0;
                int rowcount = 0;
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Days.dat"));

                List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList());
                while ( (s = in.readLine()) != null ) { 
                    if(!s.equals(""))
                    {
                        //System.out.println(s); 
                        list.add(s);
                        if(s.equals("Sunday")) { ColName[0]=s; }
                        else if(s.equals("Monday")) { ColName[1]=s; }
                        else if(s.equals("Tuesday")) { ColName[2]=s; }
                                            else if(s.equals("Wednesday")) { ColName[3]=s; }
                                            else if(s.equals("Thursday")) { ColName[4]=s; }
                        else {rowcount ++;}
                    }
                } 
                in.close(); 



            cell_value = new Object[rowcount][5];
                    for(int i = 0

    ; i< list.size();i++)
                {
                    if(list.get(i).equals("Sunday")) 
                    { n=0; m=0; }
                    else if(list.get(i).equals("Monday")) 
                    { n=1; m=0; }
                    else if(list.get(i).equals("Tuesday")) 
                    { n=2; m=0; }
                                    else if(list.get(i).equals("Wednesday")) 
                    { n=3; m=0; }
                                    else if(list.get(i).equals("Thursday")) 
                    { n=4; m=0; }
                    else 
                    { 
                        cell_value[m][n]=list.get(i);
                        m++;
                    }

                }

        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }  

        Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
        setTitle("Activity Screen");
        setSize(1000, 500);    


        JTable table = new JTable(cell_value, ColName);


          JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Activities");
          lblTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24));

          JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
          JButton btnView = new JButton("View");
          JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
          JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
          JButton btnBack = new JButton("Back");

          btnBack.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    //Execute when button is pressed
                    StartUpFrame SUF = new StartUpFrame();
                    SUF.setVisible(true);
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });  

           btnView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
             ViewActivity VA = new ViewActivity();
             VA.setVisible(true);
            }
        });  

        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
             AddActivity AA = new AddActivity();
             AA.setVisible(true);
            }
        });  



      //Lay out the label and scroll pane from top to bottom.
      contentPane.add(lblTitle, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

      contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      table.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      contentPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,20)));
      contentPane.add(table);
      add(new JScrollPane(table));

      //Lay out the buttons from left to right.
      JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
      buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

      buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
      buttonPane.add(btnSave);
      buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
      buttonPane.add(btnView);
      buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
      buttonPane.add(btnAdd);
      buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
      buttonPane.add(btnRemove);
      buttonPane.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
      buttonPane.add(btnBack);

      contentPane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

      setVisible(true);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

 }  


}



class ActivityScreen
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   new MyFrame();
 }
}
```

**The days.dat file**

```
Sunday
Advanced Open Water Dive Certificate
Sailing
Generation Next

Monday
Helping Hands
Beach Touch Rugby
Running Club
Yoga Club
Tennis Lessons

Tuesday
Recycling Club
Best Buddies
Crochet Club
Movie Club
Shooting Club

Wednesday
Table Tennis
Modern Dance
Contemporary Dance
Gavel Club

Thursday
Cooking
Gym Training
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinkedList` is of Strings. Put `LinkedList<String>` then java could check on compilation if you did not make a mistake puting another class object in your `LinkedList`. Or add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the method with unchecked operations.

Comment: So I added this to the code: List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());
But the error still ensues

Comment: You need to put in the List too: List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());